# Issue with has_many and belong_to association, can't find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a many(proposaltracking)-to-one(partner) relationship.

I am getting `undefined method 'reference' for ProposalTracking:Class` error with `@company.proposalTracking.reference`

When I run `@company.proposalTracking` it returns me the ProposalTracking object.

Here is my model:

```
class ProposalTracking < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "Proposal_Tracking"
  belongs_to :partner
end

class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :proposalTracking
end
```

What I want to get is the attributes of `proposalTracking` like

```
@company = Partner.find(params[:id])
@company.proposalTracking.reference
```

but this results in the error `undefined method 'reference' for ProposalTracking:Class`

I have read solutions where it is because since it is a one-to-many relation, the partner may have more than one track proposal so I would have to grab the first one using `.first` but I tried this and it then says

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.reference
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please better explain the associations here. I am not sure if a partner should have many proposal trackings, or just one.

Comment: it is a many-to-one proposaltracking-to-partner relationship, so a partner has many proposal trackings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :proposal_trackings
end
```

and you can access it via `@company.proposal_trackings`. But that's actually an array of ProposalTracking instances (because of has_many) that you have to iterate over to get each attribute

`@company.proposal_trackings.map(&:reference)`

Comment: The problem is I don't want just the reference attribute from that object, I want all the attributes it contains. And how come it should be proposal_trackings and not proposaltrackings?

Comment: It's a convention in Rails. If you want all attributes use the `@company.proposal_trackings` array and iterate over the elements with _each_ fro example.

Comment: thanks a lot! for some reason adding that "s" to the end worked...stupid convention. But I did use `has_many :proposalTrackings` and it worked

Comment: It's a thing with conventions. You have to know it. But believe me it's very helpful. It prevents lot's of configurations. Would you mind marking as answered?